# iOS: NSASCIIStringEncoding doesn't encode certain characters correctly

Tags: ios, objective-c, request

I have url that I am going to request data from. Here is the code.

```
 urlStr = [urlStr stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:
 NSASCIIStringEncoding];

 ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlStr]];
```

This works except when I have certain characters such as `ş`. The urlstr will return null. Is there a way around this to except certain character types? Any tips or suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: ASCII can only handle Unicode characters in the range 1-127. `ş` isn't an ASCII character.

Comment: It's "except" not "accept". Grr.

Comment: @Mathew Sorry that was my stupid mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used the following method with success in many applications:

```
- (NSString *)urlEncode:(NSString *)str {
    return (NSString *)CFBridgingRelease(CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(NULL, (CFStringRef)str, NULL, CFSTR("!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]"), kCFStringEncodingUTF8));
}
```

Note that I use this on *only* the params of the URL, so the following would work (notice I added the ş, which seemed to work, although I'm not familiar with that character):

```
NSString *baseURL = @"http://www.google.com";
NSString *paramsString = @"testKey=test value_with some (weirdness)!___ş";
NSString *resultingURLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@?%@", baseURL, [self urlEncode:paramsString]];
```

Which produces the result:

> http://www.google.com?testKey%3Dtest%20value_with%20some%20%28weirdness%29%21___%C5%9F

Comment: This is basically the method that Google uses in the Google Toolbox for Mac code so I assume it works. See https://github.com/adamotte/googleplus-ios-sdk/blob/master/OpenSource/GTMNSString%2BURLArguments.m